# Elasticsearch get id from TopHits Aggregation using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

So, to get the internal id for a document, I do this:

```cs
var hits = response
    .Hits
    .Select(h =>
    {
        h.Source.id = h.Id;
        return h.Source;
    })
    .ToList();
```

But when I do an aggregation, how would I return the same id as I do above?

```cs
var agg = response.Aggregations.Terms("inactive_pages");
var hits = agg.Buckets.Select(x => x.TopHits("top_versions").Documents<WebPage>());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at TopHits source code https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Nest/Aggregations/Metric/TopHits/TopHitsAggregate.cs#L39-L44, there are two methods that you could call:

- `Documents`
- `Hits`

Right now you're calling `Documents` and that explicitly takes document source, what if you tried to do a similar approach as you did above and use `Hits` instead?

```cs
var hits = agg
    .Buckets
    .Select(x => x.TopHits("top_versions").Hits<WebPage>.Select(h =>
    {
        h.Source.id = h.Id;
        return h.Source;
    }));
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, I didn't realize there was a Hits method!